# Method shows undefined after pushing into array

Tags: javascript

I have a class and in constructor I have name, surname, age, array of languages and etc. When I write loop and call the method it shows undefined. What is the problem.

```js
class Developer{
    constructor(a,b,c,d){
        this.name = a;
        this.surname = b;
        this.age = c;
        this.experience = d;
        this.laguages = [];
    }
    wrtie(){
        this.laguages.forEach(el=>{
           let p = document.createElement("p")
           let lang = document.createElement("p")
           p.innerHTML = el.name
           lang.innerHTML = el.languages
           document.body.append(d)
           d.append(p,lang)
        })
    }
    push(x){
        this.laguages.push(x)
    }
}
let dev = new Developer("Anna" , "Sarsgyan" , 20, 21)
dev.push(["Java" , "Andorid", "JS","Node.JS"])
dev.wrtie()
console.log(dev)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="d">

    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not defined `d`

Comment: I have id = d in my html

Comment: You have not defined `d` in `wrtie()`

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan Its always better to fetch element. Also, please make sure your snippet works so we may help

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typo in your code

```js
class Developer {
  constructor(a, b, c, d) {
    this.name = a;
    this.surname = b;
    this.age = c;
    this.experience = d;
    this.languages = [];
  }
  write() {
    const name = this.name;

    this.languages.forEach(el => {
      const d = document.createElement("div")
      const p = document.createElement("p")
      p.innerText = name;
      const lang = document.createElement("p")
      lang.innerText = el
      document.body.append(d)
      d.append(p)
      d.append(lang)
    });
  }
  push(x) {
    this.languages = this.languages.concat(x)
  }
}


const dev = new Developer("Anna", "Sarsgyan", 20, 21)
dev.push(["Java", "Andorid", "JS", "Node.JS"])
dev.write()
console.log(dev)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but why do I see undefined for el.name?

Comment: it should not be el.name, it should be this.name because you are looping in this.languages. you can have `const name = this.name` outside the forEach loop and this use it in the loop as `name`

Comment: Ok. So when I have other classes that extends from the Developer class. In that case, should wirte el.name?

Comment: i have edited my answer to show how it works

Comment: el.name will not work. el is a string (which is one of the languages such as 'Java', 'Andriod', ...)

Comment: the last questions. Why do I need this.languages.concat(x) and not simply this.languages.push(x)

Comment: we are concatenating two arrays. when we do this.languages.push(x) we are going to get `[["Java", "Andorid", "JS", "Node.JS"]]` instead of `["Java", "Andorid", "JS", "Node.JS"]`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `this.name` instead of `el.name` because `el` is an element from array of languages.
2. Use [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to push array like `this.laguages.push(...x)` so it will add each element separately in `languages` instead of entire `x` `array`.
3. To set `lang.innerHtml` just use `el` as you are looping over `this.languages` and `el` itself is each language value.

```js
class Developer {
  constructor(a, b, c, d) {
    this.name = a;
    this.surname = b;
    this.age = c;
    this.experience = d;
    this.laguages = [];
  }
  wrtie() {
    this.laguages.forEach(el => {
      let p = document.createElement("p")
      let lang = document.createElement("p")
      p.innerHTML = this.name
      lang.innerHTML = el
      document.body.append(d)
      d.append(p, lang)
    })
  }
  push(x) {
    this.laguages.push(...x)
  }
}

let dev = new Developer("Anna", "Sarsgyan", 20, 21)
dev.push(["Java", "Andorid", "JS", "Node.JS"])
dev.wrtie()
//console.log(dev)
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```